# PowerApps: How to filter a people picker combobox?

Tags: filter, powerapp

I have a combobox in a powerapps form to select a user, works good. The filtering works as text is typed in, but initially it displays the full listing of users.

Is there a way to show nothing until text is actually typed in?

ComboBox.Items = Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:PplPicker1.SearchText})

[image]

something like:
If (Not (IsBlank( PplPicker1.SearchText)), Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:PplPicker1.SearchText}))

Comment: I haven't tried this but can't you put 'Items' code to OnChange event?

Comment: Didn't work, like the concept tho

Comment: You might have to create you own control. Have a look at this https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Search-function-only-returns-results-when-input-text-field-is/td-p/47458.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

works like a charm:

If (PplPicker1.SearchText<>"", Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:PplPicker1.SearchText}))

Answer (score -1):

For this you can use client side scripting(js). Some js libraries also available which can be used like chosen.jquery [Chosen jquery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/chosen/)